# How to invoke an event by clicking on a ListBoxItem I added with code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="otherMedia" />
```

C#:

```
private void functionName(String path){
String[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
List<ListBoxItem> listBoxItems = new List<ListBoxItem>();
    foreach (var item in files)
    {         
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);
        ListBoxItem listBoxItem = new ListBoxItem()
        {
            AllowDrop =false,
            MinWidth = 10,                    
        };
                
        listBoxItem.Content = fileName;
        listBoxItems.Add(listBoxItem);
    }
    otherMedia.ItemsSource = listBoxItems;
}
```

How can I invoke an event on one of these ListBoxItem elements by clicking on them?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do things that way. Use [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview), [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview) and [styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview#styles) instead:

```
<Window x:Class="CSharpTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFileName}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void functionName(string path)
    {
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            fileNames.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
        }

        FileNames = fileNames;
    }

    //Holds the list of file names which you want to display in your ListBox
    public IList<string> FileNames
    {
        get { return (IList<string>)GetValue(FileNamesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FileNamesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileNamesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FileNames", typeof(IList<string>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    //Holds the currently selected item from the ListBox
    public string SelectedFileName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedFileNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedFileNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFileNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedFileName", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null, SelectedFileNameChanged));

    //This static method runs whenever the selected item changes (because SelectedItem is bound to SelectedFileName)
    private static void SelectedFileNameChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = (MainWindow)o;

        //Do something here to handle the change of selection
    }
}
```